# Why is the database query executed after the rest of the code?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
UpdateSettings(){
    var params     
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(db_name); 
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM main WHERE id=?`, [this.id], (err, row) => {
       console.log(row)
       params = row        
    })
    db.close()
    console.log(params) //undefined
}
```

The query is executed after executing rest of the code, how can I fix it?

Comment: Because request to db is async. You can read about using async/await . It will help

Answer (score 0):

This is how Node.js works, your db.get method is an asynchronous method (using a callback), the callback isn't executed until after the synchronous code.

It's a little confusing when you first start out, in short, params will always be undefined (in that context). You use the params inside your db.get callback function.

```js
UpdateSettings(){
    var params     
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(db_name); 
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM main WHERE id=?`, [this.id], (err, row) => {
       console.log(row)
       params = row        
       doSomethingWithParams(params)
       console.log(params); // not undefined
    })
    db.close()
    console.log(params) //undefined
}
```

I recommend having a look at: https://codeforgeek.com/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/ it should provide a better explanation than I can here.